# Removing transition from background-color doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I have a script that adds a class "notransition" to the body on the page load (it removes it after set time). I want to remove background-color and color transition from every element, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$(window).on("load", function(){
    $("body").addClass("notransition");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("body").removeClass("notransition");
    }, 1000);
});
```

```
.notransition *{
  transition-property: background-color, color !important;
  transition-duration: 0s !important;
}
```

However, I can remove every transition with code like this:

```
.notransition *{
  transition: none !important;
}
```

Is it possible to apply it only to color and background-color properties?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your quest properly it should be reverse, e.g. `setTransition` instead of `notransition` if you want to flash text on page load:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $("body").addClass("setTransition");
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("body").removeClass("setTransition");
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.setTransition {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
  transition-property: background-color, color;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="greeting">
Hi there!
</div>
```

Comment: Not really. Basically, I have a dark mode feature. When the user toggles it I want to have a small transition. When someone sets the theme to dark it still has a transition when the page is loading, so it starts from the light background and moves to dark (so the user sees a white flash when they enter the page). I think I will stick to disabling all transitions, since 150ms is not that much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code which may help you to fix your problem:

```
.notransition *{
    transition:background-color 0s, color 0s;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't disable any transitions.

Comment: I hope this time it will help

Comment: I don't understand how this could work as say I have a child div and it has a transition: all won't that override the setting you give?

Comment: @Aslamkhan Still doesn't work. I added !important at the end too, but no effect.